# Browser Selection Android

Tags: android, eclipse, browser, webview

Ive made an web browser, when I click on a link from gmail for example then it asks how I want to open that link-what browser I want to use (chrome/firefox etc). How do I make it so it asks if it wants to open it with my browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the appropriate `<intent-filter>` elements to your activity, and support them properly.

For example, here are relevant `<intent-filter>` elements used by [the AOSP Browser app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="about" />
            <data android:scheme="javascript" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="inline" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I asked this question ages ago but have come back to it. It works so far in that it comes up with the option to open the link with my browser. I am unsure how to implement it so that the browser actually opens the clicked link, because right now it just opens the default page.

Comment: @Tssomas: "I asked this question ages ago" -- pffft! It's not even six months old! :-) "I am unsure how to implement it so that the browser actually opens the clicked link" -- first, you need the right `Intent`. If your activity is called with `onNewIntent()` (i.e., you already had an instance running), the `Intent` passed to it is what you want. If instead you are called with `onCreate()`, `getIntent()` is what you want. You can then call `getData()` on the `Intent` to get the `Uri` that was used to launch your activity.

Comment: (http://teamtreehouse.com/forum/opening-a-webpage-with-android) I'm a little confused by this, I looked over the internet for this but couldn't find anything that worked, the link above seemed to be closest but crashes the app. Would it be too much to ask for an example? (Thank you by the way :) )

Comment: @Tssomas: "but crashes the app" -- off the cuff it looks fine. "Would it be too much to ask for an example?" -- you already linked to one. If you are having problems with that example, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace, and if you cannot make sense of what is going wrong, ask a fresh SO question.